# black-box behavior testing a daemon in various configurations

Tags: testing, daemon

I'm working on a node.js daemon that serves a html page (ajax enabled) which does (html5-based) file uploads through a webform, the daemon deals also with all PUT, POST, OPTIONS and GET requests that relate to the file uploads and querying the status (which don't necessarily come from the webpage it serves, any client can interact via http)

I want to programatically test a whole bunch of things, by treating the server itself (such as the fact that it's node.js) as a black box.

with inputs like:

- non-existing, empty, or various types of (incorrect) config values in the json config file
- running the program with different commandline arguments
- interacting with the webpage (navigating to it, click button, select a specific file from file selection dialog, click ok, etc, which will cause many http requests in the background)
- performing "raw" http requests programatically

and then verify that things behave as they are supposed by:

- finding entries in logfiles
- checking whether $num of processes are (still) running
- checking http response codes of all requests. (including all ajaxy-ones in the background, or responses to single requests as defined in the test)
- arbitrary commands (like downloading a file from a webserver and md5summing it)

I've been looking at some options:

- cucumber comes up often for this kind of topic, but it seems quite verbose and too aimed at business people.
- httpunit seems to assume a system is running with one specific configuration
- rspec seems to be for white-box testing ruby
- vows is too basic, no browser automation

if anyone has advice, i would appreciate it,

thanks
Dieter

Comment: Since I couldn't find what I need, I ended up putting it together myself. https://github.com/vimeo/simple-black-box

Answer (score 0):

A general solution could be http://robotframework.org/ with some standard and external libs like various http and selenium libs: http://robotframework.org/#test-libraries